# Datas from TextFormFields is null in Firebase database

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, mobile-development

I am having a hard time figuring this one out (im still new to flutter btw), I created a new screen with form that lets the user fill it out with information and after filling them out, there is a `validator` and `onSaved:` on **EACH** `TextFormField()` as of the moment, I just want the textform fields to have the datas saved to Firebase Database.

**EDIT:** I managed to make it work somehow using this code BUT the data Ive input in is `nulled` in Firebase database (second pic):

```
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await db.collection("createdoffers").add(
                            {
                              'name': offerName,
                              'type': offerType,
                              'start': start,
                              'end': end,
                            }
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

> Ive also watched some tutorial but Im having trouble making it work since its kind of a bit different to what Im trying to do (I guess its a beginners problem, Im new to programming and I fell in love with flutter lol)
>
> Now on my Firebase console, I created a new collection with some new
>   dummy data just to fill in (mind you, I still dont save INPUTS from
>   the app, just created a collection and put in some dummy data)

The image of my firebase is below:
[image]

`NULLED` data
[image]

my code is below for the screen form that I am trying to save data from INPUTS in the TextFormField and saving it all to my database by clicking the `FlatButton`

> My target for this is: **1. Save the data to firebase 2. Read that data and display it to a Container widget, I just want the C and R in CRUD for now**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddOffer extends StatefulWidget {
  AddOffer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddOfferState createState() => _AddOfferState();
}

class _AddOfferState extends State<AddOffer> {
  String offerName;
  String offerType;
  String start;
  String end;
  bool allBranches = false;
  bool selectedBranches = false;
  final db = Firestore.instance;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Color(0xFF707070),
              height: 200.0,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 20, 0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
                          color: Colors.white, size: 25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "DEAL IMAGE",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child:  Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Name",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFF707070),
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Offer Name'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                        }
                        return 'Please Enter Offer Name';
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) => offerName = value,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Type",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFF707070),
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Offer Type'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                        }
                        return 'Please Enter Offer Type';
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) => offerType = value,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 60.0),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Start",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFF707070),
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration:
                          InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Offer Start Date'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                        }
                        return 'Please Enter Offer Start Date';
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) => offerName = value,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "End",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFF707070),
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration:
                          InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Offer End Date'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                        }
                        return 'Please Enter Offer End Date';
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) => offerName = value,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 60.0),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Valid Until",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070),
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                            Text(
                              "01/01/20",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070), fontSize: 17.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Time of Active",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070),
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                            Text(
                              "12/12/19",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070), fontSize: 17.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 60.0),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Max people (optional)",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070),
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                            Text(
                              "5",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070), fontSize: 17.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Max redemption  per member (optional)",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070),
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                            Text(
                              "5",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070), fontSize: 17.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Number of redemption",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070),
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                            Text(
                              "5",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070), fontSize: 17.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 60.0),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Branches",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF707070),
                                  fontSize: 17.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Checkbox(
                                  value: allBranches,
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      allBranches = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "All Branches",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFF707070), fontSize: 17.0),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Checkbox(
                                  value: selectedBranches,
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedBranches = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Selected Branches",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFF707070), fontSize: 17.0),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                    Container(
                      width: 250.0,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        onPressed: () {
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**WHAT I TRIED SO FAR**

```
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        onPressed: ()  {
                          setState(() async{
                            await db.collection("createdoffers").add(
                            {
                              'name': offerName,
                              'type': offerType,
                              'start': start,
                              'end': end,
                            }
                          );
                          }
                          );
                        }
                      )
```

Comment: Can you please try changing how you assign the variables in the `onSaved` callback? Move `offerName = value` inside a `setState` function. Let me know if this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Hi I've tried the setState method and still, doesnt work.. Ive added it to ```what I did```

Comment: @KDC           I am facing the same issue can you tell me how you resolved it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What Went Wrong**

```dart
child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await db.collection("createdoffers").add(
                            {
                              'name': offerName, // This is null, try to change the way you save data via setState
                              'type': offerType,
                              'start': start,
                              'end': end,
                            }
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

**What you can do**

If you are continuing with this implementation, please do try `TextEditingController`.

```dart
// Declaration
TextEditingController _offerNameTextController = TextEditingController();

// Usage
TextFormField(
   controller: _offerNameTextController,
   ...
)

// Retrieving data from the input field
FlatButton(
   onPressed: () {
      // Utilize the value (eg. on your Firebase saving method
     print(_offerNameTextController.text);
   }
)
```

**Further reading**

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html

Comment: Hi I've tried the setState method and still, doesnt work.. Ive added it to ```what I did```

Comment: Sure. But have you tried this implementation above?

Comment: havent yet but I think im close to figuring this one out i think the problem lies in my TextFormField

```
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Offer Name'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                        }
                        return 'Please Enter Offer Name';
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) => offerName = value,
                    ),
```

if i can read it correctly, it only returns a value and not actually save it.

Comment: returns only the text within the ('')

Comment: But have you tried printing the value of what's inside the TextFormField? Can you check it? Use `TextEditingController` so you could retrieve the value `text` from the `TextFormField`.

Comment: I have added a solution to a similar question of yours, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412486/validator-not-saving-data-to-firebase-database/59413972#59413972. Let me know if this answer both of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the value of the `textformfield` during `onsaved`. But you forgot to save the form. Add this `_formKey.currentState.save()`;

```
    child: FlatButton(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      onPressed: () async {
        _formKey.currentState.save();
        await db.collection("createdoffers").add(
          {
            'name': offerName,
            'type': offerType,
            'start': start,
            'end': end,
          }
        );
      },
    ),
```