# Validator not saving data to Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

im currently making a flutter project as a beginner and im kind of loving it. Now Im beginning to touch the backend (just a simple CREATE WRITE btw) the problem is when I input my data, it is `null` in Firebase

I think the problem is here in my `TextFormFields` validator

```
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Offer Name'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                        }
                        return 'Please Enter Offer Name';
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) => offerName = value,
                    ),
```

I cant seem to find a way to fix this one up its only returning the text inside `''` and not saving the **actual** input hence showing a `null` in Firebase Database

> Additional details: I want the forms to **save** its data to firebase after clicking this `FlatButton`

```
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await db.collection("createdoffers").add(
                            {
                              'name': offerName,
                              'type': offerType,
                              'start': start,
                              'end': end,
                            }
                          );
                        }
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement in your code should be inside the if clause, currently it will always return `Please enter some text` since the return is outside the `if`. Therefore change the `validator` function to the following:

```
TextFormField(
  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
);
```

> Validate the input by providing a validator() function to the TextFormField. If the user’s input isn’t valid, the validator function returns a String containing an error message. If there are no errors, the validator must return null.

Answer (score 1):

**What went wrong**

You are assigning the value of `offerName` inside the `onSaved` callback, but you never called `.save()` from the `Form`'s `FormState`.

Example:

```
_formKey.currentState.save();
```

**What you can do**

Assuming that you are only after the validation of the input fields, and you are not fond of using `TextEditingController`, please see the setup below. I made the a simple app to demonstrate a simple way of validating and saving data base on your use case.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _usernameValue;
  String _passwordValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Username"),
                    // Callback when _formKey.currentState.validate(); is called
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return "Username is required";
                      } else {
                        _usernameValue = value;
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
                    obscureText: true,
                    // Callback when _formKey.currentState.validate(); is called
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return "Password is required";
                      } else {
                        _passwordValue = value;
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Save"),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  // Use the values here if the form with the unique form key has no errors
                  print("Username $_usernameValue");
                  print("Password $_passwordValue");

                  // TODO: Send data to firebase here
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Further reading**

- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation

Comment: Hi the other answer works for me but the info from ```_formKey.currentState.save();``` also helped me thank you very much! and sorry if Im asking too much lol, im still new to this kind of stuff (first programming language)